# append values to existing key in struct coldfusion

Tags: arrays, struct, coldfusion

I have a requirement which needs an "array" as value of "key" in structure.
I am using following code to do the same :

```
<cfset IndividualSurveyStruct = StructNew()>
<cfloop list="#UserIdList#" index="id">
  <cfif structKeyExists(IndividualSurveyStruct,id)>
    <cfset IndividualSurveyStruct[id] = ArrayAppend(IndividualSurveyStruct[id],SurveyId)>
  <cfelse>
    <cfset IndividualSurveyStruct[id] = ArrayNew(1)>
    <cfset IndividualSurveyStruct[id] = ArrayAppend(IndividualSurveyStruct[id],SurveyId)>
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

But I am getting this error :

> Object of type class java.lang.Boolean cannot be used as an array
>       on this line

```
<cfset IndividualSurveyStruct[id] = ArrayAppend(IndividualSurveyStruct[id],SurveyId)>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to implement this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

changing this

```
<cfset IndividualSurveyStruct[id] = ArrayAppend(IndividualSurveyStruct[id],SurveyId)>
```

to

```
<cfset  ArrayAppend(IndividualSurveyStruct[id],SurveyId)>
```

solved my issue.

Comment: FWIW, it is because arrays are modified in place, so [ArrayAppend](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arrayappend.html) returns `true` - not the array being modified.